# Assistance with WinNT MPM MaxRequestsPerChild

Tags: memory, apache2

In our `httpd-mpm.conf` file, we have this section active:

```
# WinNT MPM
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum  number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild       128
    MaxRequestsPerChild  1024
</IfModule>
```

`MaxRequestsPerChild` was originally 0, meaning no limit, but we were getting hard memory allocation errors, so as per Apache documentation, we put a finite limit on this value. We're running `/server-status` to monitor, but I can't seem to correlate this value with anything that's showing up. Would like to confirm that the change is working, and whether it should be increased or decreased.

Excerpt from `/server-status`:

| Srv | PID | Acc | M | SS | Req | Conn | Child | Slot | Client | VHost | Request |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-36 | 59996 | 0/300/2456 | _ | 35 | 265 | 0.0 | 0.42 | 1.33 | wks315.acme.local | [www.acme.com](http://www.acme.com) | NULL |
| 0-36 | 59996 | 2/180/2166 | W | 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 0.00 | 0.54 | 161.216.164.20 | [www.acme.com](http://www.acme.com) | POST /loadMenu HTTP/1.1 |
| 0-36 | 59996 | 0/281/2426 | _ | 23 | 296 | 0.0 | 0.00 | 1.11 | 184.151.190.107 | [www.acme.com](http://www.acme.com) | NULL |
| 0-36 | 59996 | 0/9/1867 | _ | 15 | 390 | 0.0 | 0.00 | 1.40 | 192.168.5.41 | [www.acme.com](http://www.acme.com) | NULL |
| 0-36 | 59996 | 0/304/2294 | _ | 59 | 218 | 0.0 | 0.05 | 0.12 | 192.168.5.231 | [www.acme.com](http://www.acme.com) | NULL |
| 0-36 | 59996 | 4/274/2489 | C | 0 | 249 | 0.0 | 0.07 | 0.90 | wks342 | [www.acme.com](http://www.acme.com) | NULL |

Legend:

| Column | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Srv | Child Server number - generation |
| PID | OS process ID |
| Acc | Number of accesses this connection / this child / this slot |
| M | Mode of operation |
| SS | Seconds since beginning of most recent request |
| Req | Milliseconds required to process most recent request |
| Conn | Kilobytes transferred this connection |
| Child | Megabytes transferred this child |
| Slot | Total megabytes transferred this slot |

I though at first it might be the last value in **Acc** "this slot", meaning that if this exceeds 1024, then the worker is restarted, but that's not the case. I've been monitoring the second value "this child", and it seems to peak around 320, never getting close to 1024. So I'm not sure what I should be looking at.